# separate data in variable in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have variable. `wer`
It has format

```
chr [1:630] "11202 398 2018" "11353 216 2017" "11511 14 2017" "11511 36 2017" "11511 37 2017" "11511 121 2018" ...
```

so i can't work with this format

```
          sample_df           first last
1    11202 398 2018  11202 398 2018 <NA>
```

i want left `sample_df`, separated by space with column's names.
So expected output

```
x1      x2   x3
11202   398 2018
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the vector to dataframe and then `separate` it into different columns

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frame(wer) %>%
    separate(wer, into = paste0("x", 1:3), sep = " ") %>%
    mutate_all(as.numeric)


#    x1    x2    x3   
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 11202 398   2018 
#2 11353 216   2017 
#3 11511 14    2017 
#4 11511 36    2017
```

---

A base R option would be

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", strsplit(wer, " ")))


#     X1  X2   X3
#1 11202 398 2018
#2 11353 216 2017
#3 11511  14 2017
#4 11511  36 2017
```

**data**

```
wer <- c("11202 398 2018", "11353 216 2017", "11511 14 2017", "11511 36 2017")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
sample_df <- data.frame(wer = c("11202 398 2018", "11353 216 2017"))

library(tidyverse)

sample_df %>% separate(wer, c("X1", "X2", "X3"))
```

Output:

```
     X1  X2   X3
1 11202 398 2018
2 11353 216 2017
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this easily in `base R` with `read.table`

```
read.table(text = paste(wer, collapse="\n"))
#    V1  V2   V3
#1 11202 398 2018
#2 11353 216 2017
#3 11511  14 2017
#4 11511  36 2017
```

---

A similar option with `data.table` would be `fread`

```
fread(paste(wer, collapse='\n'))
```

#### data

```
wer <- c("11202 398 2018", "11353 216 2017", "11511 14 2017", "11511 36 2017")
```